# TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 Disablement in authorize.net

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, authorize.net, magento-1.9.2

I got email from the Authorize.net team regarding TLS disablement as following:

Your Payment Gateway ID: 1234567
Dear Authorize.Net Merchant:
As you may be aware, new PCI DSS requirements state that all payment systems must disable early TLS by 2018. Transport Layer Security (TLS), is a technology used to encrypt sensitive information sent via the Internet. TLS is the replacement for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

In preparation for this requirement, Authorize.Net plans to disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the following dates:

Sandbox: COMPLETE
Production: September 18, 2017

We have disabled the sandbox in advance of production to allow you and your developer time to test your website or payment solution and ensure you are no longer using TLS 1.0 or 1.1 prior to September 18th.

Please contact your web developer or payment solution provider, as well as your web hosting company, to confirm that they can support TLS 1.2 for your API connections.

In addition, we plan to retire the 3DES cipher (a data encryption standard) in production soon. However, the date has not yet been finalized. We will notify you once it has.

Please refer your developer or solution provider to our API Best Practices for cipher recommendations, details about TLS 1.2 platform support, and other integration suggestions.

Note: If you are not using the current version of your web browser, please take a few moments to upgrade it now. Browsers released prior to 2014 may not support TLS 1.2. You can check your browser’s TLS support by visiting https://www.howsmyssl.com/.

Thank you for your attention to this matter and for being an Authorize.Net merchant.

i am not understanding what to do with this in magento? Currently i am using default authorize.net method of magento.

Comment: Anybody please can say that what i have to do with magento regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

try typing in your domain here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

After the analysis, you can scroll down to find the TLS compatibility results. It will display TLS 1.2 with either "Yes" or "No".

Hope that helps.